# jQuery - how to remove characters inside span tag

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to echo the page title inside a span tag. 
This works fine, except every page has the site title *and* page title within the title tag. 
How can I remove this and simply have the page title?

Ex: **Superlong Sites' Title - About Us** should be: **About Us**

My Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var href = jQuery(location).attr('href');
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('title');
    jQuery('#current_url').html(url);

    $('span#current_url').each(function() { // <---the code in question
        console.log($(this).text());
        var text = $(this).text().replace('Superlong Site\'s Title- ', '');
        $(this).text(text); 
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks ok to me... what is the problem?

Comment: Oh yeah! It still echoes the entire title.

Comment: It might be a typo in your code or title example, but could it be the mismatch between 'Superlong Site\'s Title- ' and 'Superlong Sites\' Title - '. The apostrophe is different and the spacing padding the hyphen is different

Comment: This code seams good ... some special chars might appear in this title, may a regular expression be more generic to match the "unwanted" text`:)`

Comment: Your example has the apostrophe after the s in Sites, while in the code it is Site's.

Comment: The 's was a typo in my question, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the text into an array based on the dash, then get the last item in the array:

```
console.log($(this).text());
var text = $(this).text().split('-');
$(this).text(text[text.length-1]);
```

You can trim the spaces in the front as well, if needed.

Edit - If you want it to be a little faster, you can use RegEx replace (thanks f00bar):

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^[^-]+- ?/,''));
```

If you are comfortable with RegEx this is faster, but if not then you might consider the other option as it is more explicit and maintainable.

Comment: faster : $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^[^-]+- ?/,''));

Comment: edited to include this as well, but maintainability of code always comes into question when using RegEx. providing both won't hurt anyone though. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea why these two methods don't work in IE8?

Comment: they do ... what version of jQuery are u using?

Comment: 1.6.1, think that could be the problem?

Comment: theoretically no, i was mainly making sure u weren't using 2.0 beta (since it explicitly drops all the IE8- hacks). try with more recent versions though, i know it works with 1.9.1

Comment: I used tabs instead of spaces in the code, that was the snag. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should help you :)

```
var url = jQuery(this).attr('title');
var shortUrl = url.substring(url.indexOf("- ") + 1, url.length);
jQuery('#current_url').html(shortUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `replace` function doesn't find the desired string, your title is `Superlong Sites' Title -` and you are trying to replace `Superlong Site's Title-`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#current_url').text(function(){
     return $('title').text().replace("Superlong Site's Title - ", '');
  })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try setting the span content using .html() function.